# Describe in R package DESCRIPTION a command line program as a requirement

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to write a R package that depends on `latexmk`.

However, I am unable to find how to tell in the `DESCRIPTION` of the package that it requires `latexmk` to be installed. I was hoping someone would have dealt with this before and could give me some help.

If that is not possible, is there any way to provide a custom warning message when installing a package if a command is not found on the PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `SystemRequirements: latexmk`.

See [Section 1.1.1 "The DESCRIPTION File"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) of Writing R Extensions:

> Dependencies external to the R system should be listed in the ‘SystemRequirements’ field, possibly amplified in a separate README file.

There are few more reference to the field in later sections of the manual.

Comment: aaawh, Thanks. This has been bugging me for weeks without finding the resources. 

Just to make sure, will it warn the user that he doesn't have a necessary requirement, or will it prevent installation entirely?

Comment: It will not prevent anything. You cannot test or automate this (easily) across operating systems, and distributions.  But at least it clearly states what your users need.